# shopify storefront search with graphql in Remix React

Tags: reactjs, search, shopify, remix.run, shopify-storefront-api

I am new to Remix React projects, hence I'm having a difficult time understanding the structure of the project. I am trying to create a SearchBar Component in the Header and return the first 10 products related to user input. Here is my relevant Search Component code in the Header Component:

```
function SearchForm() {
  const SEARCH_PRODUCTS_QUERY = `
  query SearchProducts($query: String!) {
    products(query: $query, first: 10) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          handle
          description
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  function handleSearch() {
    //    console.log('handle search', searchTerm);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="search"
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={(event) => setSearchTerm(event.target.value)}
      />
      <button type="button" onClick={handleSearch}>
        Search
      </button>
      <ul>
        {searchResults.map((product) => (
          <li key={product.node.id}>{product.node.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am just rendering this inside the Header Component. I am not sure if I should handle the query here. Cause I think I need the API endpoints and such to get the response body. How can I implement the handleSearch function to make it work? Is the query supposed to be in here?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably consider using the *Full Stack Component* pattern. https://www.epicweb.dev/full-stack-components

Create a resource route, then export a loader that does the query and returns the results.

Export your `SearchForm` component that will call the resource endpoint and renders the UI.

Then you can import the `SearchForm` component in your `Header`.

```js
// routes/resource.search-form.tsx

export async function loader({ request }: DataFunctionArgs) {
  const url = new URL(request.url)
  const query = url.searchParams.get('query')
  const results = await doSearch(query)
  return json(results)
}

export function SearchForm() {
  const fetcher = useFetcher<typeof loader>()

  return (
    <div>
      <fetcher.Form method="get" action="/resource/search-form">
        <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="search" />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </fetcher.Form>
      {fetcher.data && (
        <ul>
          {fetcher.data.map((product: any) => (
            <li key={product.node.id}>{product.node.title}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: but I need to use the graphql query from the storefront api for this

Comment: Yes, make the query from your loader. That's what the `doSearch` function would do.